# Is it safe to generate a temporary API key from a random generator seeded by a secure random generator?

Tags: vulnerability, java, random, key

I have a need to generate a key consisting of a given number of random characters that will be used to access resources via a public API. It should not be possible to predict the key. This is done in Java. I can use a `SecureRandom` instance but this can be slow because it needs to gather enough entropy from the underlying system. Some quick tests show that generating 1000 keys of length 100 already takes an appreciable amount of time.

Things are very speedy if instead the SecureRandom is used to generate a seed for a regular random number generator, like so:

```
Random random = new Random(secureRandom.nextLong());
Stream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(upperBound))
        .limit(keyLength)
        ... // use random ints to create key
```

Given that the random generator will be used to generate integers with a bound, I believe it isn't possible to predict the remainder of a key from its first few characters. Likewise the possession of one key would not be enough to predict the next key because a new `Random` is created for each key generation with a seed of the secure generator, so even if you could deduct what the seed for one key was you wouldn't know how the next one will be seeded.

Is this sufficiently secure? One objection I can think of is that the characters generated by the regular random generator are fully predictable based on its seed. With the seed being a Java long value, this effectively reduces the possible generated keys to 2^64 which eliminates the advantage of the vast space that a key of dozens of random characters including letters and numbers would have. Is this a fatal flaw? Can the scheme be improved without the need for getting every integer from the secure generator?

Comment: It might be better to simply change the JVM source of random data to use /dev/urandom instead of /dev/random, or just read directly from /dev/urandom.  I don't specifically know if what you're doing is secure, but I do know that /dev/urandom is highly secure, unpredictable, and re-seeded.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html

Comment: Or possibly just use a different lib that uses /dev/urandom.  I'd avoid rolling your own solution if possible.

Comment: @SteveSether Would that increase performance? Even so, it would be a platform-dependent solution and I'd rather not rely on that.

Comment: /dev/urandom doesn't block.  /dev/random does.  I'd make a wager there's another random number generator implementation that abstracts away the OS.  Maybe bouncycastle?  https://www.bouncycastle.org/

Comment: Short answer: yes, this is secure in the sense of predictability. The issue, as you found already, is blocking, which can lead to a denial of service if someone requests enough tokens. Using `/dev/urandom` is perfectly secure, but indeed OS-dependent (not sure if that's an issue; generally if this is internal software, I would say that's no problem).

Comment: I think this is a better answer, but you have to use JDK8.  https://tersesystems.com/blog/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/

Comment: Essentially it looks like in Java 8, they realized they were being a bit silly using /dev/random, since it's largely overkill unless you really need "information theoretic randomness", which is what you might care about if you're generating a one-time pad.

Comment: based on the describe threat model and usage, it should be (more than) fine. One simple improvement:  call nextInt() a random number of extra times (or the last digit of a ms timestamp or the int itself, or whatever indeterminate value is handy) _after_ using the value to make a key. This makes it a lot harder to "ride the ratchet" because you don't know which next is really next. Oh, and re-seed every now and then when you have free time; every 100 gens, or after 10 mins have passed, or whatever.

Comment: @SteveSether That's good information. I was indeed using SecureRandom.generateInstanceStrong(). Switching the algorithm to SHA1PRNG eliminated performance problems. You could post it as an answer because it solves the root issue rather than trying for workarounds.